# Create buttons in tkinter from an array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, button, tkinter

What I'm looking for is how to create a grid of buttons automatically with an iteration.

For example I have this array

```
Array = 
       [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

And I look something like

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk ()
def create_buttons ():
    global Array
    for rows in Array:
       for numbers in rows:
           button = Button (text = 'Hello')
           button.pack () 
window.mainloop ()
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what problem are you having? Have you actually tried creating a button in your loop?

Comment: I'm starting to program with Python, so i don't have a lot of experience

Comment: It creates the buttons, but vertically and it doesn't let me use the grid
I edited the algoritm in the question

Comment: have you tried searching this site for "create buttons in a loop"? there are lots of examples.

Comment: Yes, and they worked, but now the problem is that it doesn't let me arrange them in a grid, like the array

Comment: Have you tried using `grid` rather than `pack`? It's documented in many places, and there are many examples. It accepts many arguments, including a row number and a column number.

Comment: I tried it and it's half working
Thanks for the support for this noob
I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Let us put in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) what **@BryanOakley** advised you to do using object-oriented concepts.

In below code, initialize() method creates a 6x7 [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) array of zeros (as yours), then loops over its 2 axes (dimensions) to create a button on each iteration:

```
'''
Created on May 27, 2016

@author: Billal BEGUERADJ
'''

import Tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np

class Begueradj(Tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,parent):
      Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()

   def initialize(self):
      '''
      Draw the GUI
      '''
      self.parent.title("RUN ON START TEST")       
      self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
      self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

      self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent)  
      self.frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

      # Create a 6x7 array of zeros as the one you used
      self.a = np.zeros((6,7))
      for i in range(0,self.a.shape[0]):
          for j in range(0,self.a.shape[1]):
               self.b = Tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Hello')
               self.b.grid(row=i,  column= j)

# Start the main program here               
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   root=Tk.Tk()
   app = Begueradj(root)   
   root.mainloop()
```

Here is what you get after running the above program:

[image]